# How to render NV12 with DirectShow default "Video Renderer"

Tags: graph, directshow, h.264, color-space

I'm trying to develop a Video Source DirectShow filter.

The following graphs works :

[ h264 source ] -> [ Elecard H264 decoder ] -> [ Video Renderer ]
[ h264 source ] -> [ MS DTV-DVD decoder ] -> [ DMO Color Converter ] -> [ Video Renderer ]

My filter outputs h264 which will be decoded into NV12 then rendered somehow with the default, basic video renderer which only accepts RGB32.

The Video Renderer is a limitation I cannot work around. When I try to auto connect my filter to the renderer, a "AVI Decompressor" is automatically loaded but does not work.

My solution for now is to install Elecard H264 decoder which can output RGB32. I would need to install some kind of Color Converter with a high MERIT value. The default DMO Color Converter can do this for me, but its MERIT does not seem high enough. 
I don't want to rely on an expensive 3rd party solution.

I could mess with the DMO Color Convert merit to force it to load, but it doesn't seem like a nice solution. I may impact other applications on the system. Another possibility would be to develop my on Color Converter Filter, which may also get in conflict with already installed applications.

I'm unsure on how to proceed.

Comment: Default renderers typically do support `NV12`, it is the recommended YUV 4:2:0 format in Windows. Support for it might be limited in XP and older. It is not true that renderers only support 32-bit RGB.

Comment: Yes that seems odd to me. But I can't connect MS DTV-DVD decoder to the renderer directly. I'm running Windows 7